# Exception in matchingJsonPath with wiremock

Tags: json, matching, wiremock

I'm trying to stub interaction (groovy code)

```
stubInteraction(
        post(urlEqualTo("/someUrl"))
                .withRequestBody(matchingJsonPath("\$.firstName"))
            aResponse()
                .withBody("")
                .withStatus(200)
```

I receive exception

```
Problem accessing /someUrl. Reason:
com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/jayway/jsonpath/Filter;)Ljava/lang/Object;</pre></p><h3>Caused by:</h3><pre>java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[Lcom/jayway/jsonpath/Filter;)Ljava/lang/Object;
at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.matching.ValuePattern.isJsonPathMatch(ValuePattern.java:194)
```

For json:

```
{"firstName":"Jan"}
```

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dependency problem. Do you have jsonpath included via some other dependency?

If this is the case you might want to try including the standalone version with all dependencies excluded as described here: http://wiremock.org/getting-started.html

Comment: Standalone version includes old class `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` without `isAsyncStarted`, so I still have problem.